# Applications of model counting

Tags: complexity-theory, applied-theory, counting

I have been reading about model counting, a.k.a. the #SAT problem. What are the practical applications, if any, of this problem, and how exactly do they reduce to it? I have been unable to find any, though that's simply due to my own ignorance of the subject.

Answer (score 4):

A recurring application for SAT model counting in the literature is extracting predictions from [Bayesian networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network). See ["Algorithms and Complexity Results for #SAT and Bayesian Inference"](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fbacchus/Papers/BDPFOCS2004.pdf) and 
["On probabilistic inference by weighted model counting"](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0004370207001889/1-s2.0-S0004370207001889-main.pdf?_tid=df1b702a-79d3-11e4-a853-00000aab0f02&acdnat=1417491341_88602b5ae2fd10713db0db64ff7a44be).